# What are some tips for installing a small shed?

Tags: concrete, planning-permission, shed, slab

I want to put in a small shed to store my push lawn mower and perhaps a few other things.  Our village's website states we need a permit:

```
SHEDS – Must be either anchored to a concrete slab or have footers 42” deep
Inspections Required for Sheds: Footers (prior to pouring concrete) rough
framing and a final inspection.
```

Which is easier/cheaper?  concrete slab or footers?  How do I go about buying a shed?  Would I need to do the concrete/footers myself and then have home depot deliver it?  We live in upstate NY if that matters (lots of snow in the winter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any place that sells pre-built sheds in your area would likely have advice on site preparation for delivery.

I don't know what the soil's like in your area, but if you're going to hit bedrock before 42", it'd likely be easier to put in a slab;  If you're likely to hit lots of tree-roots, the slab might be a better choice (so you don't kill a tree, and have it fall on your new shed)  For most other times, I'd personally go with footings, but I live in an area that's clay and easy to dig.  (other than tree roots).

Some pre-built sheds are made to sit on a slab, as they have no floor; this can make it easier to get things in/out of the shed, as you don't have the step-up.

... also, rather than buying from Home Depot or similar, look to see if there are Amish or Menonite areas near you -- they often have businesses that do this sort of pre-built structure construction.  It might be a little more expensive, but you can get them customized to a specific size, material, etc ... it's what I'd do if I wasn't going to build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no exemption for non-permanent structures so you can avoid the inspection, etc.  Many places have exemptions for 100 square feet or smaller.

Really it depends if you are going to do other things in the shed, but if it were me I would just do the sonotube things.  42" is a long way though.  You must be way up north.